# Insert a new column before a certain column based on row header-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am simply trying to search for a specific column based on the header and insert a new column right before it (so to the left of the column). Right now my code searches for all columns that even contain my search and inserts a new column 2 columns to the left. For example I want to search for the header that says `Paid to Date` ONLY but it even inserts a column next to `Commission Paid to Date` etc.

```
Sheets(NewSheet).Select 
Set ColHeaders = Range("A4:CD4").Find("Paid to Date") 
If ColHeaders Is Nothing Then 
    MsgBox "Paid to Date Column was not found." 
    Exit Sub 
Else 
    Columns(ColHeaders.Column).Offset(0, -1).Insert 
End If
```

Comment: Since you know that you are inserting 2 columns to the left, how about changing the offset by 1? to offset(0,0) or you could remove the offset part

Comment: There are more criteria to Range.Find() method.  One allows you to set it to only look at the whole cell and not part.  Google `Range.Find()`.

Comment: Additionally: I recommend to read (and follow!) [VBA Best Practices: Avoid using select or activate](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate) and [VBA Best Practices: Never assume the worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet) to improve your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the time it took to confirm a solution, this seems to be answered in the comments.

- Remove the Offset as it will insert in column before by default
- [Read the documentation for `Find` here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-find-method-excel) and specify the argument `LookAt` to be `xlWhole` (put a value of 1, [as per enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241368(v=office.12).aspx))